# How to pass string as a argument to d3.csv() function and process further for plotting heatmap in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, date, csv, d3.js

I want to plot histogram using csv data using d3.js. I'm referring [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3202354) link. In that tutorial they are using local file csv data but in my application data comes from the web-socket so, I'm thinking that I can collect this data and create one string as a csv data and pass this string to the d3.csv or d3.csv.parse function. meanwhile, I'm getting stuck at one point because my data is not properly populating over web-page.

Web-socket server is sending this file data line by line :

```
date,bucket,count
1468332421041000,40000,2
1468332421102000,30000,6
1468332421103000,30000,8
1468332421116000,30000,10
1468332421117000,30000,2
1468332421139000,30000,2
1468332421155000,50000,2
1468332421158000,40000,2,
1468332421164000,30000,12
```

This date is in epoch so, In the client side I need to convert it in human readable format.

**Client html program -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tile {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var csv_data = '';
    var flag = true;

        if ("WebSocket" in window)
        {
            // Let us open a web socket
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3333");
            ws.onopen = function()
            {
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
            {
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                if(flag)
                {
                    csv_data = evt.data +"\n"
                }
                else
                {
                    var b = received_msg.substring(17)
                    var a = received_msg.substring(0,13)
                    var dateVal = a;
                    var date = new Date(parseFloat(dateVal));
                    csv_data += date.getFullYear()  + "-" + 
                                    (date.getMonth() + 1)  + "-" + 
                                    date.getDate() + " " + 
                                    date.getHours() + ":" +
                                    date.getMinutes() + ":" +
                                    date.getSeconds() +" "+
                                    date.getMilliseconds() +","+b+"\n"
                }
                flag = false;
                readCsv();
            };
            ws.onclose = function()
            { 
                alert("Connection is closed...");
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
            alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        }

var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse,
    formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %d");


var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scale.linear().range(["white", "steelblue"]);

// The size of the buckets in the CSV data file.
// This could be inferred from the data if it weren't sparse.
var xStep = 864e5,
    yStep = 100;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function readCsv()
{
    d3.csv(csv_data, function(buckets) {
    // Coerce the CSV data to the appropriate types.
    buckets.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.bucket = +d.bucket;
        d.count = +d.count;
    });

    // Compute the scale domains.
    x.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.bucket; }));
    z.domain([0, d3.max(buckets, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

    // Extend the x- and y-domain to fit the last bucket.
    // For example, the y-bucket 3200 corresponds to values [3200, 3300].
    x.domain([x.domain()[0], +x.domain()[1] + xStep]);
    y.domain([y.domain()[0], y.domain()[1] + yStep]);

    // Display the tiles for each non-zero bucket.
    // See http://bl.ocks.org/3074470 for an alternative implementation.
    svg.selectAll(".tile")
        .data(buckets)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "tile")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.bucket + yStep); })
        .attr("width", x(xStep) - x(0))
        .attr("height",  y(0) - y(yStep))
        .style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count); });

    // Add a legend for the color values.
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(z.ticks(6).slice(1).reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (width + 20) + "," + (20 + i * 20) + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .style("fill", z);

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 26)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(String);

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", width + 20)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text("Count");

    // Add an x-axis with label.
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(d3.time.days).tickFormat(formatDate).orient("bottom"))
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Date");

    // Add a y-axis with label.
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"))
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .text("Latency");
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know how I can provide string to parse as a csv data to d3.csv function and after processing it what changes I want to do further? Because In that tutorial date is only in the format i.e. yyyy-mm-dd But In my scenario date is in (after converting to human readable format) i.e. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss mmm format.

Comment: Instead of converting into single line and then parsing it, convert into a json array.

Comment: @Dragon_Slayer- can you show me with simple example so that I can understand better what you have to tell me!