# How I can scale x-axis of graph with time format containing milliseconds using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, axis

I want to generate heat-map using d3.js by using csv data. For heat-map plotting I'm trying to set x-axis,y-axis and z-axis. But I'm facing issues while setting x-axis of the graph.

**sample csv data :**

```
var csv_data = "date,bucket,count\n07:31:01 001,10000,12\n07:31:01 119,50000,13\n07:31:01 128,60000,53\n07:31:01 200,90000,24\n07:31:01 555,75000,56";
```

**program code-**

```
    <script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse,
    formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %d");

//
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scale.linear().range(["white", "steelblue"]);

// The size of the buckets in the CSV data file.
// This could be inferred from the data if it weren't sparse.
var xStep = 864e5,
    yStep = 100;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var csv_data = "date,bucket,count\n07:31:01 001,10000,12 005\n07:31:01 119,50000,13\n07:31:01 128,60000,53";

    var buckets = d3.csv.parse(csv_data);
    buckets.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = d.date;
        d.bucket = +d.bucket;
        d.count = +d.count;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.bucket; }));
    z.domain([0, d3.max(buckets, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

    // Extend the x- and y-domain to fit the last bucket.
    // For example, the y-bucket 3200 corresponds to values [3200, 3300].
    x.domain([x.domain()[0], +x.domain()[1] + xStep]);
    y.domain([y.domain()[0], y.domain()[1] + yStep]);

    // Display the tiles for each non-zero bucket.
    svg.selectAll(".tile")
      .data(buckets)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "tile")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.bucket + yStep); })
      .attr("width", x(xStep) - x(0))
      .attr("height",  y(0) - y(yStep))
      .style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count); });

  // Add a legend for the color values.
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(z.ticks(6).slice(1).reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (width + 20) + "," + (20 + i * 20) + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .style("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 26)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(String);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width + 20)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text("Count");

  // Add an x-axis with label.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Time");

  // Add a y-axis with label.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .text("Latency");

    </script>
```

**Currently Graph is showing like this :**

[image]

How I can set x-axis of graph with data whatever into the string? what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `x axis` represents a time scale. You need to pass in valid date objects instead of strings. In your particular example, this would become:

```
buckets.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = timeFormat.parse(d.date);
  d.bucket = +d.bucket;
  d.count = +d.count;
});
```

where timeFormat is a [d3.time.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md) formatter:

```
var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%H:%M:%S %L');
```

To parse milliseconds you can use [the following directive](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md):

> %L - milliseconds as a decimal number [000, 999].

In your CSV data, the dates should follow the specified format. for ex:

```
07:31:01 001,10000,12005
13:34:01 119,50000,13
17:39:01 128,60000,53
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/756hk6jh/):

[image]

Comment: @
kmandov - your jsfiddle is not showing any blue ticks on the heat-map? It is only showing x, y and z axis.

Comment: @kmandov- Actually you need to saw my question then you can understand what I want to do. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887211/how-to-pass-string-as-a-argument-to-d3-csv-function-and-process-further-for-pl?noredirect=1#comment65148377_38887211]